# sync call inside async call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, exec

what happens when I call a sync function inside a async function?

like

```
execFile('test', function(){
  execFileSync('test');
});
```

will the 2nd call block the browser window ?

Comment: Of course the second call will block when it start executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Do Not Release Zalgo! (joke :))
http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony

Answer (score 3):

The `sync` call will block the event loop until it finishes doing his work, so yes, everything will be blocked.

That's the main reason that every module, who has a `sync` version of their methods, recommends to use them only for testing.

You can see an example in the `fs` [module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).